# Angular CLI 6: How to consume a library sub-project in the main application?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6

I've got an Angular 6 project that's made of up a main application, and a separate sub-project that is a library. I'm trying to consume this library from the main application, and I can't seem to get it working.

In the `tsconfig.json`, I have the following `paths` configuration:

```
"paths": {
  "@my-company/my-package/*": "dist/my-package/*"
}
```

And then in the main app, I import the library like so:

```
import { ButtonModule } from '@my-company/my-package/button';
```

However, when I build the main application, I get tons of errors about not being able to find modules. For the above import statement, I'll get this error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/jattardi/code/myproject/dist/my-package/button'
```

However, if I check the `dist/my-package` directory, there certainly is a `button` directory containing the type definitions.

The reason my imports have subpaths, e.g. `@my-company/my-package/button` instead of just `@my-company/my-package` is to make it tree-shakeable. Not sure this is possible. Since this is an Angular 6/ng-packagr generated build, do I lose this ability?

Answer (score 0):

I was hit with the same error when trying to consume in the main application. My answer will not solve that case as I am trying to get my lazy loaded module, I moved into the new Angular6 library, to work.

I was able to publish my library project to npm and consume it in the main application as an npm dependency. For eg: @santony/ngx-material. May be as a workaround you could do that until this is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still facing this problem, there's a "how to" at `ng-packagr`'s documentation:

https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/blob/master/docs/secondary-entrypoints.md

Basically,

> All you have to do is create a `package.json` file and put it where you want a secondary entry point to be created.
> The contents of `my_package/testing/package.json` can be as simple as:

```json
{
  "ngPackage": {}
}
```

And also, in dev application, I've added the path reference to the secondary endpoint, so it worked:

```json
"@my-company/my-library/another": [
  "dist/my-library/another"
]
```